# How to clear value of html.displayfor on search button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to clear value of html.displayfor on search button click. Currently previous value and current value are appending on number of times we click the search button.

_Test1 Partial view has search button

```
$('#btn-search').on('click', function () {
        var data = { UserName: $('#txtusername').val(), Locality: $('#Locality').val() }
        $('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid({
            requestType: 'post',
            reload: true,
            data: data
        });
    });
```

Display for is in another partial view _Test2 Partial View

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => userIdCount)
```

Comment: What is the rendered content of your DisplayFor? Depending on the content, you might use a selector to update the element(s) `$("#userCount").html(value)`

Comment: How to clear the value of displayfor each time i click submit button....because displayfor and submit are in different partial views

Comment: It does not matter whether they are different partials or same partials. Eventually all the code will generate a single HTML page markup only.

Comment: @Shyju still my value is not getting cleared

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the Index View or Main View so that it can capture all elements:

```
$('#btn-search').on('click', function () {
    var data = { UserName: $('#txtusername').val(), Locality: $('#Locality').val() }
    $('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid({
        requestType: 'post',
        reload: true,
        data: data
    });
});
```

From there you can include this to modify your data of `@Html.DisplayFor(m => userIdCount)`

```
$("#userIdCount").html('');
```

or

```
$("#userIdCount").text('');
```

Comment: It keeps appending